# Enable C++14 in Qt Creator 4.0 Clang Static Analyzer using CMake

Tags: cmake, clang, qt-creator, c++14, clang-static-analyzer

I use some C++14 features with Clang 3.8 in my project. The build system is CMake, so I run clang static analysis like this:

```
$ scan-build cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang \
/path/to/source
$ scan-build make
```

This way building and analysis work perfectly well, but I also want to use it from Qt Creator through GUI integration. When I press **Analyze** -> **Clang Static Analyzer**, clang stops on the first file using C++14 features with nonzero error code and errors like:

> ```
> error: <a_cool_c++14_feature> is a C++14 extension
> ```

I added

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)
```

to my topmost `CMakeLists.txt`, but it didn't work. I also tried to set `CXX_STANDARD` with `set_property` command for all targets, but I got the same result in Qt Creator, while building by hand from console works well.

How to use C++14 in Clang Static Analyzer from Qt Creator GUI?

Comment: http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2014/04/install-use-clang-static-analyzer-cmake.html Should be unrelated to Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `-std=c++14` in Option > C++ > Code Model.

Mine is like this :

```
-Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-unused-macros -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-global-constructors -Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments -Wno-documentation -Wno-shadow -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wsuggest-override -std=c++14
```

Note : 
You have to reopen each file for it to take effect.
If you can't edit it, you have to enable the plugin "Code model" first (help > about plugins...) and restart QtCreator

Answer (score 2):

What helped me is the following line in the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```